# Is 'for' necessary in 'I urge ( ? ) anyone to take a look'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, for

This is the sentence here.

> I urge (  ?  ) anyone to take a look at the fact that he was a prince in a small kingdom.

Is the 'for' necessary in this sentence in the blank (question mark)?
And what is the difference between the two sentences (with *for* and without *for*) in meaning?

Comment: No for. It's fine but this is editing and not really allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> I **urge** everyone **to** consider the fact that ...
>
> I **urge** **for** taking into account the fact that ...

I don't think "urge for anyone" is correct.

Comment: I urge for is not grammatical in English.